# Is the exponential martingale of Brownian motion uniformly absolutely continuous?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, uniform-integrability, local-martingales

Let $M = \{M_t\}_{t\ge0}$ be the [exponential martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential) of Brownian motion $W= \{W_t\}_{t\ge0}$, that is,
$$
M_t = \mathcal E(W)_t = \mathrm{exp} \left( W_t - \frac{t}{2}\right).
$$
**Question:** Is $M$ uniformly absolutely continuous, that is, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that, for every measurable $A$,
$$
\mathbf P(A)<\delta \Rightarrow \sup_{t\ge0}E(M_t;A)<\epsilon\ ?
$$

---

What I know is the uniformly absolute continuity is implied the [uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability), but the exponential martingale $M$ is only uniformly integrable on finite time interval but [not on $[0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726231/prove-that-a-martingale-is-uniformly-integrable).

Any comments or hints will be appreciated. TIA...

---

**EDIT:** If not, can we guarantee a slightly weaker result that
$$
\mathbf P(A)<\delta \Rightarrow \limsup_{t\ge0}E(M_t;A)<\epsilon\ ?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W_t$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt N$, where $N$ is standard normal, it follows that
$$
\mathbb E\left[M_t\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(\sqrt{t}x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac t2\right)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac 12\left(x-\sqrt t\right)^2\right)dx=1
$$
and $M_t\geqslant 0$ hence $(M_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ is bounded in $\mathbb L^1$. If the claim in the question (or the version with the $\limsup$) was true, we would get uniform integrability of $\left(M_t\right)$, but it has been shown that it was not the case in a linked thread.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I realized that it is not uniformly absolutely continuous, since basically, for an $L^1$ bounded martingale, the uniformly absolute continuity is equivalent to the uniform integrability. Well, so, how about my second claim which I added in the EDIT part?

Comment: It does not hold, by using uniform integrability on a compact interval.