# How to show the following random variable is not uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, analysis

For iid random variables $P(X_1=1/3)=1/2=P(X_1=5/3)$, let $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$. Is $Y_i$ uniformly integrable? I am not sure how to show that?

If I used definition, if $Y_n$ is not uniformly integrable, then there exists $\epsilon_0>0$, for every $\delta>0$ with $P(|X_1\dots X_n|>M)\le \delta$,

$$
E[X_1\dots X_n; |X_1\dots X_n|>M]>\epsilon_0
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Y_n$ is a martingale. To show that the martingale is not uniformly integrable, I follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726231/prove-that-a-martingale-is-uniformly-integrable).

So all I need to show is $Y_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Let's take a look at $log{Y_n}$. It's the sum of n IID RVs: $$Z_i=log{X_i}$$ Note that $\mathbb{E}[Z_i] < 0$.

Now by SLLN,
$$ \frac{Z_1 + Z_2 + ... Z_n}{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Z_1] < 0 $$
$$ \implies Z_1 + Z_2 + ... Z_n \rightarrow -\infty$$
or, $$ log{Y_n} \rightarrow -\infty \implies Y_n \rightarrow 0 \text{  a.s.}$$